# JavaFX: Lag with many buttons

Tags: java, button, javafx, lag

I made a simple minesweeper game by making a button for each cell.
When I have 9x9 cells (81 buttons) everything works smooth.

But when I change the grid size to 16x16 (256 buttons) or 16x30 (480 buttons) I get serious lag. The hover effect takes almost a second when I move the mouse.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: There's probably something wrong with the way you've coded it...

Comment: Ok, so thats not normal behaviour?

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it was due to an inner shadow on the grid border.

Comment: Hmm. That shouldn't  be, but I think I remember a question a while back with a Canvas with an effect that degraded performance like that.